# How to convert a byte to the correct decimal representation?

Tags: rust, ascii, bit

I have a function that checks a bit in a specific index of a string (converted to byte representation):

```
fn check_bit(s: String) -> bool {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes(); // converts string to bytes
    let byte = s[0]; // pick first byte
    // byte here seems to be in decimal representation
    byte | 0xf7 == 0xff // therefore this returns incorrect value
}
```

after printing and doing arithmetic operations on the `byte` variable, I noticed that `byte` is a decimal number. For example, for the ASCII value of char `b` (`0x98)`, `byte`  stores `98` as decimal, which results in an incorrect value when doing bitwise operations on them. How can I convert this decimal value to correct hex, binary or decimal representation? (for `0x98` I am expecting to get decimal value of `152`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> noticed that `byte` is a decimal number

An integer has no intrinsic base, it is just a bit pattern in memory. You can write them out in a string as a decimal, binary, octal, etc., but the value in memory is the same.

In other words, integers are not stored in memory as strings.

> For example, for ascii value of char b (0x98), byte simply stores 98 as decimal

ASCII `b` is not 0x98, it is 98, which is 0x62:

```
assert_eq!(98, 0x62);
assert_eq!(98, "b".as_bytes()[0]);
assert_eq!(98, 'b' as i32);
```

> How can I convert this decimal value to correct hex, binary or decimal representation?

Such a conversion does not make sense because integers are not stored as strings as explained above.